# Saving vs refreshing the same code changes how it looks?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm working on a very simple react app -just a tic tac toe game- and I've been trying to use CSS to get the content centered in the middle of the page. I wrote the css, I saved it, and the content centered automatically in my browser. Then I refreshed the page and it reverted back to the top. If I save again, it goes back to the center. The code/css is the exact same, so why could this be happening?

EDIT: 
If I have this code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <p> Text </p>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and this CSS:

```
body {
    font: 14px "Century Gothic", Futura, sans-serif;
    margin: 20px;
    background:linear-gradient(45deg, #ed492f, #a540db); ;
    color: black;
}

.game, body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

When I save, it recompiles and updates automatically to look like this

[image: seems to be working properly]

If all I do is refresh the browser, the text moves to the top:

[image: when browser is refreshed]

I could be missing something very obvious as this is really simple code but I'm lost.

Comment: Can you please share the code which is related to your question? Thank you!

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM to see what CSS is applied when you refresh and the style "reverts"? Please also update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code.

Comment: sorry/thanks - I updated the question